# Can't scrape the text from class (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have issue with getting the data from website with lotto draws for statistics, I have tryied bunch of different parsers but every time the content it returns is "none"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.opap.gr/lotto-draw-results"
user = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"}
req = requests.get(url, headers = user)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
i = 1
while i <= 6:
    for draw_num in soup.findAll("li", {"class": "draw-result-number-{}".format(i)}):
        print(draw_num.content)
        i += 1
```

the piece of html code from the website:

```
<ul class="circles"> <li class="draw-result-number-1">1</li> <li class="draw-result-number-2">2</li> <li class="draw-result-number-3">12</li> <li class="draw-result-number-4">14</li> <li class="draw-result-number-5">20</li> <li class="draw-result-number-6">49</li> <span class="plus_symbol" style="display: inline;">+</span> <li class="highlighted draw-result-number-bonus" style="display: inline-block;">8</li> </ul>
```

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910520/how-to-scrape-page-with-beautifulsoup-page-source-not-matching-inspect-element/52910658?noredirect=1#comment92732288_52910658, essentially the same problem - you're trying to open a webapp with `request` and `request` cannot run javascript

Comment: @RockyLi I'm a bit confused now, I've never used selenium before, can you help me with the code?

Comment: Answered, install selenium package by using `pip install selenium`

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, the data is not embedded in the html but is retrieved from an additionnal API call :

https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/5103/last-result-and-active?status=results

You can parse it to get the winning numbers :

```
import requests
req = requests.get("https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/5103/last-result-and-active?status=results")
data = req.json() 
print(data["last"]["winningNumbers"])
```

It seems the url path is static, in JS it's building the url dynamically and 5103 means it's `Lotto` games, see [this file](https://www.opap.gr/combo?browserId=other&minifierType=&themeId=opapgrtheme_WAR_opapgrtheme&languageId=el_GR&b=7010&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_common_draw_results_INSTANCE_7ViMTivVgje2:%2Fjs%2Fmain.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_common_draw_results_INSTANCE_7ViMTivVgje2:%2Fjs%2Fkino.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_common_draw_results_INSTANCE_7ViMTivVgje2:%2Fjs%2Fpropo.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_common_draw_results_INSTANCE_7ViMTivVgje2:%2Fjs%2Fproto.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_common_draw_results_INSTANCE_7ViMTivVgje2:%2Fjs%2Flotto.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_commons_draw_search_portlet_DrawSearch_INSTANCE_OILJVEhcpTNg:%2Fjs%2Fmain.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_commons_draw_search_portlet_DrawSearch_INSTANCE_OILJVEhcpTNg:%2Fjs%2Fpropo.js&eu_singularlogic_opap_web_commons_draw_search_portlet_DrawSearch_INSTANCE_OILJVEhcpTNg:%2Fjs%2Fkino.js&t=1539892584000)

Comment: That works fine, but there's no way to get those numbers straight from html? I want to get numbers from other games from the same site.

Comment: @PrzemekRzepa if you look at the JS file I've linked there is a code for each game 5103 is for "Lotto", 2100 is for "Super3", 1100 is for "Kino" etc... for instance for Kino : https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/last-result-and-active?status=results

Comment: I see, but how can I take results from let's say 20 last draws of kino?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how `selenium` can be used in your case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capa)
driver.set_window_size(1440,900)
driver.get('https://www.opap.gr/lotto-draw-results')
time.sleep(15) # wait for the website to load in selenium process

plain_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
```

All of your element will be contained in the soup.